# Maintain a unique session ID in Angular and Node JS

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am building a new WEB application where I want to achieve the below from the Application.

1. Build a Angular UI.
2. Create a NODE JS middleware that calls my Back end system.

My first request to the back end system gives a Unique Context Key as one parameter in response. I need to use that Unique Key in every following request later on.

How do I do this? Can we maintain a new session ID with the key in the UI side or node side?

I am new to the development.

Comment: Read [MDN Web Developer Guide - HTML Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies).